# Почему при проверке последней строки программа всегда выдает NO?

Tags: c, строки

```
К примеру если в файле написано ([abc]{def}) То должно вывестись YES однако выводится YES
                                )[abc]{def}(                     NO                   NO
                                {}[]()                           YES                  NO
```

И так при любом примере в последней строчке выводится NO. Пробовал отследить через отладку, но там в основном показываются значения указателей, так что где происходит ошибка найти не получается.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>


typedef struct _INFO
{
    char s;
    struct _INFO* next;
}INFO;
typedef INFO* STACK;

int Push(STACK* stack, char s)
{
    INFO* temp = (INFO*)malloc(sizeof(INFO));
    temp->s = s;
    if (!temp) return 1;
    if (!*stack)
        temp->next = NULL;
    else
        temp->next = *stack;
    *stack = temp;
    return 0;
}
int Pop(STACK* stack, char* s)
{
    if (!*stack) return 1;
    INFO* temp = *stack;
    *s = temp->s;
    *stack = temp->next;
    free(temp);
    return 0;

}

int main (void)
{  
   freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
   freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
   char str[1024];


   char *estr;








   while (1)
   {
      estr = fgets (str,sizeof(str),stdin);
      if (estr == NULL)
      {         
         if ( feof (stdin) != 0)
         {  

            break;
         }


      }

          STACK head = NULL;
    bool flag = true;
    char * sp = & (str[0]);

    char s, s_1;
   while ( ( * sp ) != '\n' )
    {
        char s = ( * sp ) ;
        if (s == '(' || s == '{' || s == '[')
        {
            Push(&head, s);
        }
        if (s == ')' || s == '}' || s == ']')
        {
            if (!head) { flag = false; break; }

            if (head->s == '(' && s == ')') Pop(&head, &s_1);
            else if (head->s == '[' && s == ']') Pop(&head, &s_1);
            else if (head->s == '{' && s == '}') Pop(&head, &s_1);

       }
       ++ sp ;
    }
    if (!head && flag)
        printf("YES\n");
    else
        printf("NO\n");


   }



   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не наблюдаю: https://ideone.com/MM4MeU Как воспроизвести ваш эффект?

Comment: А какую задачу должна решать данная программа?

Comment: `while ((*sp) != '\n')` - очень похоже, что в последней строке отсутствует перевод каретки, и цикл выходит за границу массива, находя там всякий мусор.

Comment: Программа должна определить в каких строках правильно расставлены скобки и вывести  да или нет

Comment: https://ideone.com/s4za77 Здесь программа не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас она не срабатывает, если последняя строка не завершается символом `\n`. Замените

```
while ( ( * sp ) != '\n' )
```

на

```
while(*sp)
```

и попробуйте еще раз.

Comment: Спасибо! Всё работает.

Comment: Здесь "спасибо" выражается в птичке слева от ответа ))